# Remove image border in twentyeleven theme

Tags: images, css, child-theme

I am unable to remove the fine grey border around all of my images in the twentyeleven theme.
I'm using a child-theme and tried changing my style.css with the following:

```
img[class*=”wp-image-“], #content .gallery .gallery-icon img {
    border:none;
}
```

But unfortunately it's not working. Can somebody maybe help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the grey background around the images, removing this should help:

```
.wp-caption {
background: #eee;
}
```

Or you could switch it to transparent

```
.wp-caption {
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, that didn't work out. twentyeleven theme by default is having a border in grey color around all images and I'm unable to remove this.

Comment: Combine both what you have and what Steve suggests. Also, make sure that your CSS is loaded after TwentyEleven's CSS, or use `border: none !important;` for a higher priority.

Comment: I tried your suggestions:
/* Image borders */
img[class*=”wp-image-“], #content .gallery .gallery-icon img { 
border:none !important;
}
.wp-caption {
background: #eee;
}
None of it worked so far. How can I change the load order, so that my child-themes css is loaded last?

Comment: On a default twentyeleven theme this suggestions combined should all work. Can you provide us a link?

Comment: www.beethetraveler.com - I looked with the webdeveloper toolbar in chrome and it seems like the default style.css is loaded but I don't know why!

Comment: Your childtheme-css got rendered with some unicode-problems. Replace the " on your 
img[class*=â€wp-image-â€œ], #content .gallery .gallery-icon img { 
border:none !important;
} with regular ones.

Comment: It worked - I replaced the code and now everything worked as it should. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad i could help. Pls remember to mark the question as answered.